# React router v6 and relative links from page within route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi am trying to update project using react router to v6. I get the basics but am struggling with relative links.

We have a page that renders reference documentation for a given item by 'id'. The documentation can have links to other 'sibling' material, using sibling id. In other words the user can navigate around the docs without ever leaving the same basic route (parameterised by 'id').

I have made a little [repro on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-relative-links-zbp2tg?file=/src/App.js), with essential code below.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function GenericPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <p>Document id: {id}</p>
      <div>
        Links from within page don't work:
        <Link to="./foo" className="link">
          Foo
        </Link>
        <Link to="./bar" className="link">
          Bar
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        Working top nav:
        <Link to="docs/generic/foo" className="link">
          Foo
        </Link>
        <Link to="docs/generic/bar" className="link">
          Bar
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/docs/generic/:id" element={<GenericPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Have tried using `../{id}`, etc to no avail.

Maybe this is by design but it seems a bit odd to disallow a link to sibling pages using a simple relative name. All pretty normal in regular web dev.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised I hadn't run across this one yet, but it seems to be by design. There's a discussion [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8350) that you may find illuminating, or frustrating. There does appear to be *some* workarounds though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised I hadn't run across this one yet, but it seems to be by design. There's a discussion [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8350) that you may find illuminating, or frustrating. There does appear to be *some* workarounds though.

Apparently the `".."` means to "go up one `Route`". When there's only one `Route` the code is defaulting to the root `"/"` "route" that the app is being rendered on.

You can restructure your routes to match the path structure.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/docs">
    <Route path="generic">
      <Route path=":id" element={<GenericPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Now the relative links appear to work as you and I, and I suspect many others,  expect them to.

```
function GenericPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <p>Document id: {id}</p>
      <div>
        Links from within page now work:
        <Link to="../foo" className="link">
          Foo
        </Link>
        <Link to="../bar" className="link">
          Bar
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-and-relative-links-from-page-within-route]

Comment: Thanks Drew Reese, I am marking your question as answer. The one from @clj750 is very similar but you provided a little more info and link to discussion!

Answer (score 2):

All previous answers are correct and well illustrate the design of the react router v6. However, imho. the proposed solutions are *workarounds* so that, in this case, the links act as expected.

Much simpler however would be to use the relative="path" flag in the `<Link />` component. See the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.1/components/link#relative):

> By default, links are relative to the route hierarchy, so .. will go up one Route level. Occasionally, you may find that you have matching URL patterns that do not make sense to be nested, and you're prefer to use relative path routing. You can opt into this behavior with relative

This has the big advantage to also function as expected if the component which is rendering the `<Link />` component is not in the same hierarchie as the "last" route element, which will often be the case for Layout components.

In your case, simply replace

```
<Link to="./foo" className="link">
```

by

```
<Link to="./foo" relative="path" className="link">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your parameterized route under the main one, like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/docs/generic" element={<GenericPage />}>
    <Route path=":id" element={<GenericPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

The nesting allows the nested path to get tacked onto the end of its parent, so the final route is `/docs/generic/:id`.

After that, update your in-page links so you only pass the parameter value to the `to` prop instead of the whole route:

```
<div>
  <Link to="foo" className="link">
    Foo
  </Link>
  <Link to="bar" className="link">
    Bar
  </Link>
</div>
```

This allows you to change the actual route value ("/docs/generic") in your router without having to update the links in your GenericPage component.

[See it on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-relative-links-forked-7je6le?file=/src/App.js).