# React-router-dom v6 recursive, nested routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some data which has a structure of tree but sometimes it gets update from backend side how can I use this tree recursively
I tried this kind of structure but react router dom don't let me to create this kind structure, for example : I want to go  /a ,  /a/b ,  /a/c , /a/b/d

this is the sample route tree which I want to implement but ignore the elements I just created which I want show you.

```
<Route path='a' element={<Thing item={a} />}>
  <Route path='b' element={<Category item={b} />}>
    <Route path='d' element={<Content item={d} >}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path='c' element={<Category item={c} >}/>
</Route>
```

example mapping

```
 {legislationsData?.map((item) => (
          <React.Fragment key={item.Id}>
            <Route
              path={item.Path}
              element={item.Children?.length > 0 ? <Category Children={item.Children} /> : <ContentList item={item} />}
            />
            {item?.Children?.map((sub) => (
              <React.Fragment key={sub.Id}>
                <Route path={item.Path + sub.Path} element={<ContentList item={sub} />} />
                {navigationDatas.map((nav) => (
                  <Route
                    key={nav.Id}
                    path={item.Path + sub.Path + nav.Path}
                    element={<ContentDetail item={nav} />}
                  />
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
```

This is the sample data which I am working on it:

```
"Data": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "ParentId": "0",
      "Name": "Genelge",
      "Path": "genelge",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": "2",
          "ParentId": "1",
          "Name": "General",
          "Path": "general",
          "Children": []
        },
        {
          "Id": "3",
          "ParentId": "1",
          "Name": "External",
          "Path": "external",
          "Children": [
            {
              "Id": "4",
              "ParentId": "3",
              "Name": "Terminal"
              "Path": "terminal",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "5",
      "ParentId": "0",
      "Name": "law",
      "Path": "law",
      "Children": []
    },
    {
      "Id": "6",
      "ParentId": "0",
      "Name": "Ithalat Things",
      "Path": "ithalat-things",
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": "7",
          "ParentId": "6",
          "Name": "KTO",
          "Path": "kto",
          "Children": []
        },
        {
          "Id": "8",
          "ParentId": "6",
          "Name": "Genelgeler",
          "Path": "genelgeler",
          "Children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: What is the mapping from the "Data" to routes and components you want to render? Do you have an example for something you've tried? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I added my old mapping but it is not enough to handle because tree is getting bigger and it is not recursive

Comment: How many levels of depth is your data? 3 like in your data example, or is it indeterminate and truly need to be recursive?

Comment: it is indeterminated and truly need to be recursive because there can be unlimited children, I tried to make recursive algorithm for Route in diffrent component but react-router-dom dont let me to use it in this Routes

Comment: Does something like this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549205/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese thanks, probably it is going to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

add path="/:id" to make routes dynamic

Following this doc solution may help you: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/recursive-paths

Comment: What happens when you nest another route with `path=":id"`? OP appears to be using `react-router-dom@6`, BTW.

Comment: but I need a paths like a/b/c/d/e  like file structure

Answer (score 0):

in react to dynamic route you have to use /:id otherwise you have to use a fixed URL for nesting you can check this for more details: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/overview